# Android Fixed Tab at Bottom

Tags: android, tabs, fixed

I want fixed tabs at bottom such I can use the same tabs in each activity. I have a layout that shows the tabs at bottom but how can I add TextView above of that?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
    Intent intent;
    Resources resources = getResources();

    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    tabSpec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tabSpec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

This is my TabActivity. And I have ThirdActivity whose layout is like that(It does not seem but TextView is in RelativeLayout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   

TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I want ThirdActivity should contain the tabs "tab1" and "tab2".

Comment: see this link http://kandroid.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/tabview-part-5-tab-control-at-bottom-of-app/

Comment: Ok, I will explain my problem in a detailed way. I have 3 tabs for example and I'm creating different activities for these tabs. But after clicking the first tab, another activity(different from the 3 activity) will be created and in this new activity, I also want these 3 tabs at bottom. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tutorial in [link above](http://kandroid.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/tabview-part-5-tab-control-at-bottom-of-app/) posted by Dipak, to create the layout of the TabHost.

Then go ahead an create a class to handle the TabActivity and create 3 separate activity classes for each of your tabs. Link these with the layout described above.

There is a [tutorial here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1) showing you how you can create a tab host.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm doing like that but I have a problem. I want to talk about second tutorial you mentioned. There is a TabActivity class and there are two tabs for two Activities. But what I want is : I need one more Activity such that this Activity will be started by the first Activity. Due to tutorial, I'll have a ThirdTab Activity. Also, this ThirdTab Activity should contain the TabHost, that is what I want exactly. I hope I can tell my problem in a clear way.

Comment: You'll have to go away and try to add the third tab activity and host yourself. Then if needed come back and edit your post with some code , outlining where you are stuck or what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

**I think @adaclks want to make Tab bar `consistent for all the activities`**.....it means that whenever you want to open any new activity or child activity, you want to keep tab bar at bottom in every activity.

If i am not wrong, then you can use [**`ActivityGroup`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) concept, as this class is deprecated, you can use [**`Fragment`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and [**`FragementManager`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) API instead.

Here is an example for ActivityGroup: [Use Android ActivityGroup within TabHost to show different Activity](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity)

Comment: Thank you, I succeded using ActivityGroup but I have one more problem. When I clicked first tab, I'm using ActivityGroup A and after a button click, moving to Activity B. When I'm in Activity B, I'm clicking the first tab but it doesn't move to A. How can I manage this?